# touch events on UITextField rightView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have several text fields which compromise a registration form . When the user hit submit and made invalid inputs the wrong fields are marked with an icon as rightView.

The rightView i use is a custom UIImageView subclass which has it's:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

overwritten to display a alert to tell the user what exactly is wrong with this field.

The problem is that the touchesBegan method is never called. Why is the view not receiving touch events when I touch it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to enable user interaction of images to TRUE

```
[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check whether your view is on the upper level of views (that it's not overlayed by another transparrent view)
And also check for view's user interaction set to ENABLED
Also check that you tap directly on the view, this method is called only when you tap within your view's bounds
I also recommend you to read a bit about UITapGestureRecognizer class may be this would be more convenient way to use...